# SQL: creating a new table that tells the user which manager is for each employee

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench

So i need to make a table that lists the managers for each employee. I know that I need to relate the manager ID with the employee ID but I dont know how to go about it

```
create table employee
(EmpID int, 
name varchar (50),
title varchar (50),
managerID int, 
salary int
);
```

when executing the command

```
select * from employee;
```

should give

```
EmpID   name               title        managerID
 ----------------------------------------------
'101', 'Robert Jones',   'Sales Person', '102'
'102', 'Liz Farnandezs', 'Sales Manager','106'
'103', 'Mathew Richards','Sales Person', '102'
'104', 'Ethan Lubatkin', 'Sales Person', '105'
'105', 'Stuart Little',  'Store Manager', NULL
'106','Samantha Porter', 'Manager',       NULL
```

I am still new to SQL so anything that can help me solve this problem would be great.

I would need a result to look like this

```
EmpID   name               manager        managerID
 ----------------------------------------------
'101', 'Robert Jones',   'Liz Farnandezs', '102'
'102', 'Liz Farnandezs', 'Samantha Porter','106'
'103', 'Mathew Richards','Liz Farnandezs', '102'
'104', 'Ethan Lubatkin', 'Stuart Little',  '105'
'105', 'Stuart Little',   NULL,            NULL
'106','Samantha Porter',  NULL,            NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't need an additional table for that, you have all the needed info in this table.

You just need to use join (two instances of the same table, one for employees and one for managers) in order to get the manager's details:

```
SELECT emps.empID, emps.name, managers.name as manager, 
managers.empID as managerID
FROM employee as emps LEFT JOIN employee as managers 
ON emps.managerID = managers.empID
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is something like this, where you `LEFT JOIN` the same table in order to have both the employee and his direct manager on the same row:

```
SELECT
    e1.empID
    , e1.name
    , e2.name as Manager
    , e2.empID as ManagerID
FROM employee e1
    LEFT JOIN employee e2 ON e1.managerID = e2.empID
```